# Using Html.fromHtml to set custom Typeface

Tags: android, string-formatting

I found this list of HTML-Tags that are (supposedly) supported for HTML.fromHtml to create a Spanned-Text:

http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Now is there ANY way to set a custom Typeface with the Font-Tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [set font at runtime, Textview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483110/set-font-at-runtime-textview)

Comment: this is not a duplicate of set font at runtime. It's a more specific case. He want's to set the font for only *part* of the text. This is more challenging than simply supplying a typeface from a ttf assett.

Comment: did you get the solution for this problem?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

## Outdated. See other answers.

---

No, there's no way to do so. You can [take a look at the `Html` implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/text/Html.java). As you will see, the `font` tag supports `size` and `color` only.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use a `<font>` tag with a `face` attribute. This has been possible since at least Android 1.5 ([see source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/text/Html.java#686)).

The value of the `face` attribute will be passed to the [`TypefaceSpan(String)` constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TypefaceSpan.html) to create the Spannable. For example, use "monospace", "serif", or "sans-serif".

Comment: I can get this working with default fonts like monospace - but how can I use custom fonts that I have in my assets directory? I tried all the default paths to the assets directory - but no luck :(

Comment: Same issue.. Any luck?

Comment: Question is about custom font.