# Android - Html.fromHtml() with custom fonts

Tags: android, html, fonts, android-typeface

I'm trying to assign HTML text into a TextView. Here's a sample of the HTML:

```
<font face="myCustomFont1">Some Text</font>
<font face="myCustomFont2">Some More Text</font>
```

I'm using `Html.fromHtml(myHtmlString)` to do this.

If the fonts are system fonts, such as sans-serif-xxx, then everything works fine. The problem is using custom .ttf / .otf files which I add to my application.

Is there a way to make fromHtml recognise custom fonts? I couldn't find anything online other than this link: [Using Html.fromHtml to set custom Typeface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314507/using-html-fromhtml-to-set-custom-typeface) (look at the 2nd answer - inside the comments)
but it leaves the issue without an answer.

Comment: The accepted answer says: `No, there's no way to do so.` I wouldn't say it's **without an answer**...

Comment: Thanks, I can read. The accepted answer is wrong. I was actually looking at the 2nd answer which states that I should use the "face" attribute which works. The comments ask about custom fonts, but no answer was given. I've edited my question to make this more clear.

Comment: `The accepted answer is wrong.` ... **really**?!

Comment: The accepted answer says "As you will see, the font tag supports size and color only" - this is wrong, since "face" is also supported and size is *not* supported.

Comment: `face` is supported only as "internal" typefaces.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to make fromHtml recognise custom fonts?

Not for the syntax that you are proposing. You are welcome to fork the `Html` class and add that in. Given the way that `Html` is implemented, you aren't going to be able to enable this via a subclass, AFAICT.

Using a `TagHandler`, you *may* be able to pull this off without forking `Html`, but a `TagHandler` is only going to be invoked for an unrecognized HTML tag. Since `<font>` is recognized, the `TagHandler` won't be invoked for it. If you are in control over the HTML, though, you could create a `<gil>` tag and use that as a `<font>` equivalent that routes through a `TagHandler` that you provide. I haven't used `TagHandler`, which is the reason as to why I hedge as to whether this can work.