# Rendering Kannada (Indic) Text on Android

Tags: android, text-rendering

I was recently developing an android application where I wanted to display kannada text in the TextView. I went through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483110/set-font-at-runtime-textview), now the problem is the glyphs(character sequence) are not rendered/interpreted properly.
I also found [this](https://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/bdd0b9b6a1609901/3697a43979ff3696?pli=1#3697a43979ff3696) discussion pretty usefull  .
Now my question is - "Is it possible to integrate a layout/shaping engine (responsible for rendering the text properly) in an application.

Any help in this regard would be helpful.

Thanks !!

Comment: An app related to Dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bitmap fonts  and your own rendering engine till Android supports

Comment: @swik, can you  please describe your solution. I am facing a similar issue. Check thi question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455923/kannada-font-on-android-ics

Comment: @swik   Can you share How to make use of bitmap fonts? any example would be grateful! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

What version of Android are you targeting? Pre-2.3 Android has very poor support for any Indian language whatsoever. 2.3 introduced support for Hindi, but Dravidian languages are still missing. Based on this fact is my hunch that Android 2.3 and later probably might render Kannada text better.

Also, emulators have known issues with text rendering in some languages. I suggest testing on a real device.

Comment: I'm developing on my hTC phone which runs on android 2.3 and it has the same rendering problems...